# Function stops after click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simulate two click to open a menu. The first one opens the menu and the second the submenu but after the first click() the function stops.

This is my JS code:

```
function open_menu(id_menu, id_sub_menu) {
    $('.sous-domaines a#lien-domaine-'+id_menu).click();
    $('a#lien-menu-'+id_sub_menu).click();
}
```

I call my function in HTML with this code:

```
<span onClick="open_menu('0', '116')">Open sub-menu</span>
```

Comment: HTML and click event code please??

Comment: Also any errors in the console section ??

Comment: in the console i have this:
Erreur : uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Comment: Looks like a error in your page.. Check which line in your script its pointing too

Comment: Your console should tell you exactly which line of code is causing the error.

Comment: don't you have to bind a click handler for the elements you are trying to trigger? as in it does not mimic a real click on an anchor tag if you have nothign bind to it

Comment: It's strange the console indicates me no line

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it too fast maybe.

Wrap the second one in a `window.setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can give this a try, it is pretty much waht you had, other than the fact i don't have menu open somewhere

http://jsfiddle.net/tRg3e/2/

I think the .click() only works if you have a handler attached, it does not trigger the native click on the element.. I tried it without handler and the link does not go

Comment: @Amar try this http://jsfiddle.net/tRg3e/2/ if you don't bind click handler for the element you are triggering then it does not work

Answer (score 0):

can you do something like this ?  set a bool after first click

```
var IsClick = false;

function open_menu(id_menu, id_sub_menu) {
    $('.sous-domaines a#lien-domaine-'+id_menu).click();
     if (IsClick){ fnSecondClick();}   
}

function fnSecondClick() {
//open submenu

}
```

or something like this - on click check if menu is visible:

```
function open_menu(id_menu, id_sub_menu) {
    $('.sous-domaines a#lien-domaine-'+id_menu).click();
     if ($(element).is(":visible")){ fnSecondClick();}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stray away from 'onClick' declared in elements like that, it's bad practice if I do recall. Nonetheless, it still works.

If you could provide some HTML code it would help clarify the idea but you could set a trigger event for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wrN2u/3/

**EDIT:** With a toggle - http://jsfiddle.net/wrN2u/18/

Comment: It's not deprecated, just bad style -- it's a good habit to separate your code (and CSS) from your HTML as much as possible.